# Reactively check if a file is available

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm developing a shiny app that lets you import some data, manipulate, and plot them.
When you are satisfied with the analysis, you can generate a .xlsx file with a python script (I'm using reticulate to make it work inside the shiny app):

```
server <- function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input$run_py, {
    # pass variable from R to Py
    py$df <- avg.spread()
    py$var <- var.spread()
    py_run_file('py_export_excel.py', local = FALSE, convert = FALSE)
  })
}
```

The .xlsx file is not ready instantaneously, so I need to have a different button that lets you download the file.

```
server <- function(input, output){
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "file.xlsx",
    content <- function(file) {
      file.copy("test.xlsx", file)
    }
)}
```

Everything works up to that point, but I don't like the idea to have to press two different buttons to make only one thing.
I want to have a reactive handler that keeps checking if the file exists and automatically prompts you to download it. Is there a way to make the following code reactive?

```
if(file.exists("test.xlsx")) {
  # download code
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `invalidateLater` to repeat (after a delay) a reactive block. Try this:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
.log <- function(...) message(format(Sys.time(), format = "[ %H:%M:%S ]"), " ", ...)
.maxtime <- 60
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    actionButton("doit", "Long process ..."),
    downloadButton("dnld", "Download!")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    .log("hello world")

    started <- reactiveVal(Sys.time()[NA])
    shinyjs::disable("dnld")
    # just for this answer
    if (file.exists("61240116.txt")) warning("file exists: '61240116.txt'", call. = FALSE)

    # this is your "long process", here I just delay and touch the
    # file; the important parts to preserve are 'disable' and
    # 'started' (or similar)
    observeEvent(input$doit, {
      shinyjs::disable("dnld")
      .log("starting a long process ...")
      started(Sys.time())
      system("sh -c '{ sleep 5 ; touch 61240116.txt; }'", wait = FALSE)
    })

    # this is the work-horse here: it starts whenever 'started' is
    # triggered, and keeps working as long as it has not been too long
    observe({
      req(started())
      d <- difftime(Sys.time(), started(), units = "secs")
      if (file.exists("61240116.txt")) {
        .log("... done!")
        started(Sys.time()[NA])
        shinyjs::enable("dnld")
      } else if (d > .maxtime) {
        .log("timed out")
        # might need to do some damage-control here
      } else {
        .log("... cycling, ", round(d, 1))
        invalidateLater(1000, session)
      }
    })

    # simple/naive download handler
    output$dnld <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() "61240116.txt",
      content = function(file) file.copy("61240116.txt", file)
    )
  }
)

# Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5020
# [ 16:56:08 ] hello world
# [ 16:56:17 ] starting a long process ...
# [ 16:56:18 ] ... cycling, 0
# [ 16:56:19 ] ... cycling, 1
# [ 16:56:20 ] ... cycling, 2
# [ 16:56:21 ] ... cycling, 3
# [ 16:56:22 ] ... cycling, 4
# [ 16:56:23 ] ... cycling, 5
# [ 16:56:24 ] ... done!
```

1. Start the app, note that `Download!` is disabled (the first `shinyjs::disable`);
2. Click the `Long process ...` button, note on the console you should see some status messages.
3. After about 5 seconds, the download button should become enabled, and you can now download the file.

[image: shiny page, before and after]

The "engineering" of this mini-app:

- `started` is two-fold: start the 1000ms cyclic-invalidation, as well as keep this check from running forever. (It is certainly possible (if you "set" `started` in multiple places) to break this construct.) Using "time" may not be ideal for your situation, nor is it completely fool-proof (e.g., a heavily-laden system might need more time).
- I set and reset `started` to `Sys.time()[NA]` for three purposes: first, it needs to always be `POSIXt` and not something "recent"; second, `difftime` gets upset when it's merely a number (e.g, `0`), since that needs a time origin; and third, `req` will cause the `observe` block to early-terminate if it is some form of `NA` (or something else non-truthy ... see [`?req`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/req.html)). We rely on this behavior.
- `shinyjs` is used to disable the download button so that *we* control when something is available for download.